# MVC best practice question: producing XML data extracts from a model?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I'm using an MVC framework to develop an app that produces data extracts in XML format. An extract file is produced hourly using cron.

I have a model called DataExtract that stores the date range for the extract. I also have a view containing the XML used to generate the extract.

There's no controller for it, since it's not part of the front end.

Can anyone advise on the best practice here? Is it okay to parse the XML view directly from the model when producing the extract file?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... the way I see it, "I don't want the report to be viewable through the application", means it is ok to break the MVC pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm mis-reading this: you are creating an xml file every hour but you don't want this file to be read through the application? Shouldn't the htaccess file prevent that (if the file exists then open that instead of the application)?

Is it that you don't want the cron file to be accessible from the address bar?

I am running a cron job as well. Like you I am running it through ZF.

I have split my bootstrap setup to a separate file. In my index.php file I include the bootstrap file, then call $application->run. In my cron file I include the bootstrap but don't run the application. At the top of the file I have:

```
//deny remote access
if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']))
{
  die;
}
```

This snippet of code stops anything other than the server from running the cron job.

I agree with @guided1. You are not showing anything to the screen, the V part of MVC is out the window. My cron file is handling the part of the C (calling whichever Models).

Comment: Thanks Dickie. Like you, I'm including a bootstrap file but not running the application. Is the view part really out of the window? I have a complex XML file that I want to parse just like a regular view template. The only difference is that I don't have a controller. I am wondering whether it's cleaner to parse the view in my cron script or in the model. Your answer leads me to think the cron script would be better, since it's acting as the controller in this scenario.